# Conditional formatting of plotly table databars in Dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, conditional-formatting

I have my Dash application 99% of the way to where I want it and am just stuck on the conditional formatting of my databars in my tables. The databars are working fine but they are currently calculating % off the min and max of the df['target']. As you can see, the target is different for each row, and I want the databar % to be calculated off each rows corresponding df['target']

Below is the code I currently have for the databars and table generation, as well as a snippet of the current finished product. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def data_bars(df, column, target_column):
    if (df[column] == 0).all():
        return []
    # function code here
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    min_value = 0
    max_value = df[target_column].max()
    ranges = [
        ((max_value - min_value) * i) + min_value
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = (max_bound / max_value) * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #FFB6C1 0%,
                    #FFB6C1 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles


def generate_table(dataframe):
    columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in dataframe.columns]
    style_data_conditional = []
    for col in columns:
        if col['name'] in ['1','2','3','4','5','6', '7', '8']:  #### ADJUST AS WEEKS ARE ADDED #####
            style_data_conditional += data_bars(dataframe, col['id'], 'target')
    return dash_table.DataTable(
        data=dataframe.to_dict('records'),
        sort_action='native',
        columns=columns,
        style_data_conditional=style_data_conditional,
        style_table={
            'width': '95%',
            'overflowX': 'scroll',
            'margin': '10px 0',
            'margin-left':'30px',
            'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
            'maxHeight': '600px' # add a maximum height to enable vertical scrolling if needed
        },  
    
        style_cell_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {'column_id': 'Player.Last.Name'},
                'textAlign': 'left',
                'fontWeight': 'bold',
                'backgroundColor': 'white',  # keep the background color of the fixed column white
            },
            {
                'if': {'column_id': 'Player.Last.Name'},
                'position': 'sticky',
                'left': '0',
                'borderRight': 'thin lightgrey solid',
                'zIndex': '999',
            },
        ],
        style_cell={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
            'maxWidth': '180px',
            'minWidth': '100px',
            'whiteSpace': 'normal',
            'height': 'auto',
        },
        style_header={
            'backgroundColor': 'maroon',
            'fontWeight': 'bold',
            'color': 'white',
        },
        page_size=40,
    )
```

[image: Output]